# Joining confirmation email

Tags: email, wp-mail

When a super admin adds a network user to a blog via wp-admin/user-new.php where does that confirmation email come from? How do I change? It says incorrectly comes from

> Wordpress@example.com

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how to close this post. I used WP better emails plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-better-emails/ on the subsites and it removed the wordpress email address. (I was only using it on the main site before so it didn't work.) Thanks.

Comment: Wait for two days and then use the check mark below the arrows.